# Calling Stored Procedure during initialization of ActionServlet

Tags: spring, web-applications, struts, ibatis

Can a Stored Procedure be called during initialization of ActionServlet [init() method] using ibatis?

Comment: if i am correct `ActionServlet` is something in Struts and not struts2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming ibatis is initialized before `ActionServlet.init` is executed, which it will be if you initialise it in a ServletContextListener.

However, I would consider whether you should be doing your application initialisation in a subclass of `ActionServlet.init`. I would do it in an implementation of ServletContextListener's `contextInitialized` method instead.

There's a post from 2002 by Craig McClanahan that explains why this is better practice:

"The reason for this is that the servlet spec does *not* guarantee that a
servlet will be loaded once and then left in memory the entire lifetime of
the app, although in principle most containers do that for heavily
requested servlets. For example, it is entirely legal for a container to
throw out the Struts controller servlet, and then re-initialize it again,
as many times as it wants to, within the lifetime of a webapp.

The nice thing about ServletContextListener is that you're guaranteed that
contextInitialized() and contextDestroyed() are only called at the times
you need them (webapp startup and webapp shutdown), no matter what happens
with servlets and JSP pages in the middle. But this only works on a 2.3
or later system, where this API was added."